# Is there a way to enforce StringIO.seek() for non-ascii sequence to operate on bytes instead of characters (the same as for text file)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

When implementing a unit test for function searching for something in a large text file, I met the problem with `io.StringIO.seek()`. Unlike normal text file streams it operates on characters and not bytes, so I'm unable to place a file pointer in the middle of a multi-byte character. Is there any workaround for this behavior?
Is there any elegant way to create a text file stream containing specific contents without creating an actual file?

Comment: Can you use `io.BytesIO` instead?

Comment: @Barmar original function operates on text streams only

Comment: In the case of a text file stream, this seek will usually cause a decoding error. So it seems like what you really need to mock is a way to trigger this exception, to test your error handling.

Comment: Nope: the seek does not decode anything. But the following read() may raise UnicodeDecodeError

Comment: That's what I meant. The seek into the middle of the byte sequence is the cause of that read error.

Comment: So for unit testing, you just need to mock a `read()` call that raises the exception, so you can test the error handling.